# Adding button text / label inside SpeedDialAction - Material-UI v1 / React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I am trying to add labels to nested `<SpeedDialAction />` components, and have button text displayed next to icons like so:

[image]

but it seems like `children` do not get rendered:

```
...
<SpeedDialAction
  key={action.name}
  icon={action.icon}
  tooltipTitle={action.name}
  onClick={this.handleClick}
>
  Foo
</SpeedDialAction>
...
```

[image]

I also tried using the `ButtonProps` prop as [listed in the docs](https://material-ui-next.com/lab/api/speed-dial-action/) but that did not do the trick either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take a look at the `SpeedDialAction` source code https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/6f9eecf48baca339a6b15c5fcfb683cba11e4871/packages/material-ui-lab/src/SpeedDialAction/SpeedDialAction.js

- The title of `Tooltip` only shows on hover, but it can be easily done by changing default state to `true`, eg: `state={ tooltipOpen: true }` in SpeedDialAction.js file.
- However, `Tooltip` component in `SpeedDialAction` has no reference, so there is no easy way to `setState` from outside.

The **easiest solution** is to create a custom `SpeedDialAction` component.
`SpeedDialAction` component contents only `Tooltip` and `Button`, which it's hard to modify.

There is the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/9zpyj4o0zo
You can simply add SpeedDialAction.js file to your project.

**Update:**
Removed `onClose` event in `Tooltip` in codesandobox. Fixed the problem where title disappear after click.

[image]

Comment: totally! one small addition, `<Tooltip>` has a prop called `disableTriggerHover`. It would probably be a good idea to set it to `false` so that tooltips do not disappear `onMouseLeave`

Comment: @Dimitry_N Thanks for the add on. I'm not a big fun of Material UI. The animation is too slow in general, and keeping all components inside DOM isn't very efficient in React.

Comment: @Dimitry_N Minor bug fix. removed `onClose` event in `ToolTip` component in my demo